# Android OOM when creating bitmap from view

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

i am creating a bitmap of layout. Its working fine in most of the devices but in few samsung devices, its throwing OOM. Below is the code I am using to convert the layout to bitmap

```
private void enableViewCache() {
    viewToConvert.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    viewToConvert.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    viewToConvert.buildDrawingCache(true);
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromView() {

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewToConvert.getDrawingCache());
    viewToConvert.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    viewToConvert.destroyDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    return b;
}
```

I am getting OOM at Bitmap.createBitmap call. I have checked most of the OOM bitmap issues in stackoverflow which mentioned about using sampling and all but I dont know how to implement that in this usecase.

Comment: Are these old devices? Maybe try using a lower compression quality

Comment: OOM is occuring in the Bitmap.createBitmap method itself. Its mainly happening in old devices like samsung s2 and note

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but in MOST cases you don't want to extract a `Bitmap` from a `View`. What you usually want is to maintain the bitmap on a different place (LRU Cache maybe?). My guess would be the view's drawing cache is the issue.

Anyway, the problem is probably the way you're handling a large bitmap. [Read this article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) so you know how to sample, scale down, and other techniques so you don't get OOM.